# Why does an async method needs to return a future?

Tags: dart

I am trying to wrap my head around [this](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/). I have to be understanding incorrectly.

Example:

```
Future A() { ..}

Future B() async{
   await A();
   print "123";
}
```

Why does `B` need to return a `Future`?
Doesn't `await` make `B()` synchronous? i.e., It waits for `A` to completely finish and then executes the `print` statement.

Then, What is the necessity for `B` to return a `Future`?

Comment: If `await` behaves the same as in other languages like JavaScript/C# than it is not waiting, but rather letting your write synchronous-looking code that executed asynchronously - see JavaScript explanation - https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Comment: You can think of "await" as meaning "asynchronous wait". In other words, it is logically a *wait* (in the sense that it does not execute the rest of `B` until after `A` completes); but it is also *asynchronous* (in the sense that it does not block `B`'s caller). Since the logical wait operation is asynchronous, it forces `B` to be asynchronous (and thus return a `Future`).

This does mean that `async` "grows" through the code. This can be alarming at first, but is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async` and `await` **don't** make async execution sync. There is no way to do that.

All `async` and `await` does is to make async code look more like sync code. It is just syntactic sugar. Everything that can be done with `async` and `await` can be done without it as well.

Instead of deeply nested `.then(...then(...then(...).catchError())).catchError(...)` distinct statements, for loops, `try`, `catch`, `finally` can be used which makes code easier to write, read and reason about.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart language an `async` modifier allows to use an extended syntax in asynchronous functions (and, of course, asynchronous functions which in most cases cannot return result immediately until they not completed, they return a wrapper of the future result which called in Dart a `Future`).

Using extended syntax means a possibility to write asynchronous operations in the same manner if you wrote a synchronous operations.

In order to be able in a single function use both synchronous and asynchronous operations the extended syntax allows to use operator `await`.

With operator `await` the asynchronous operations will look like they are synchronous operations because an operator `await` perform a work which can be called `asynchronously wait until the operation will not completed`.